# Let $1 \le p < \infty$, and let $a, b \ge 0$. Prove $(a + b)^p \le (1 + \epsilon) a^p + C_\epsilon b^p$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $1 \le p < \infty$, and let $a, b \ge 0$. I would like to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $C_\epsilon > 0$ depending on $\epsilon$ such that
$$
(a + b)^p \le (1 + \epsilon) a^p + C_\epsilon b^p
$$

I could not find a reference for this inequality or a name, so if anyone knows where I could find a proof that would be helpful.

Comment: So $C_{\epsilon}$ does not depend on $a,b$ and $p$?

Comment: This boils down to $(1+x)^p\leq (1+\epsilon)+Cx^p$, which is elementary because univariate

Comment: This was asked and answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853822/proof-of-the-inequality-abp-ap-leq-epsilon-ap-c-epsilon-b?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the help!