# $(a+b)^p\leq(1+\epsilon)a^p+C_{\epsilon}b^p$

Tags: inequality

I would need a hint to prove the following statement :

> For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $C_{\epsilon}>0$ such that for
> every couple $a,b\ge 0$ we have  $(a+b)^p\leq(1+\epsilon)a^p+C_{\epsilon}b^p$

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2853822/42969

Comment: @MartinR, thanks, Iam not sure I understood why "For $x>x_\varepsilon$, it is evident as well with $C_\varepsilon = (1+x_\varepsilon^{-1})^p$." in the first link

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853822/proof-of-the-inequality-abp-ap-leq-epsilon-ap-c-epsilon-b for a more detailed solution.

Comment: @edamondo: This may be late, but I wrote an answer to this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4367870/121671) based on Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts: if either $a = 0$ or $b=0$ the result is trivial.

If $b \not = 0$ you can divide everything by $b$ and write $t = \dfrac ab$ to arrive at $$(t+1)^p \le (1+\epsilon)t^p + C_\epsilon.$$

What you need to show is that, for every $\epsilon > 0$, the function $$\phi_\epsilon(t) = (t+1)^p - (1+\epsilon)t^p,\quad t \ge 0,$$ is bounded above. Try the first derivative test.