A certain inequality bound
Why does the following estimate hold for any $p \in [1,\infty)$, and $\delta \in (0,1)$,
$$
 \big ||a-b|^p - |a|^p - |b|^p \big | \leq \delta |a|^p + \frac{C_p}{\delta^p} |b|^p
$$
If we use convexity of $|x|^p$ and use something like Jensen's inequality, there won't be delta terms in front of $|a|^{p}$. Thank you.

Have you more detailed attempts ?

unfortunately..no others attempts came to my mind.. appeareance of $\delta^{p}$ in numerator and denominator also suggest to use young inquality result that is seen wikipedia, which also seems to fail because there is just p.

Would you mind sharing where you saw that estimate, in case the context could be useful?

In this post it has been shown - in the notation of that post - that
$$||x+y|^t-|x|^t-|y|^t|\leq C(|x|^{t}|y/x|+|x/y||y|^{t})$$
where $t>1$ and $x,y$ are real numbers and $C$ is only dependent on $t$.
Now, for $a>c$, let $x=a$ and $y=c$ giving $0<|y/x|=|c/a|=\delta^t<1$, giving
$$||a+c|^t-|a|^t-|c|^t|\leq C(\delta^t|a|^{t}+\frac{1}{\delta^t}|c|^{t})$$
Now let $b = -c$ and $t=p$ to achieve
$$||a-b|^p-|a|^p-|b|^p|\leq C(\delta^p|a|^{p}+\frac{1}{\delta^p}|b|^{p})$$
I reckon that should be the answer. In particular, in your question there should be $\delta^p|a|^{p}$, not $\delta|a|^{p} $. Since for symmetry reasons, exchanging $a \leftrightarrow b$ does not change the LHS, so in the RHS the constant cannot be pinned to only one variable, and also the $\delta^p$'s should appear on both variables.

OP's inequality could still be true even with an asymmetry, in fact the way to make it symmetrical again would be to simply use a $\min$ on the RHS between the current RHS and the one where $a$ and $b$ are swapped

I was inspired by zhw's answer to this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2853822/1104384.\
This is a partial answer because I wasn't yet able to turn my constant $C_{p,\delta}$ into the desired $C_p/\delta^p$, but maybe someone else can use this as a first step to proving the expected inequality.
Suppose $a \neq 0$ (the inequality will then be true for $a = 0$ if it's true otherwise).
Then
$$\big ||a-b|^p - |a|^p - |b|^p \big | \leq \delta |a|^p + C_{p,\delta} |b|^p$$
is true iff the following is true, where $c := b/a$ :
$$\big ||1-c|^p - 1 - |c|^p \big | \leq \delta + C_{p,\delta} |c|^p$$
Now, consider the functions
$$f : c \in \mathbb{R} \,\,\longmapsto\,\, |1-c|^p - 1 - |c|^p\\
g : c \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \,\,\longmapsto\,\, \frac{f(c)}{|c|^p} = \frac{|1-c|^p - 1 - |c|^p}{|c|^p} = \left|\frac{1}{c}-1\right|^p - \frac{1}{|c|^p} - 1 = f\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)$$
We have that $f(c) \to 0$ as $c \to 0$, thus there exists $\eta > 0$ such that:
$$|c| \leq \eta \quad\Longrightarrow\quad |f(c)| \leq \delta$$
Moreover, $g$ is continuous on the closed set $\{|c| \geq \eta\}$ and $g(c)$ tends to $0$ as $c \to \infty$, hence one can show that $g$ is bounded on $\{|c| \geq \eta\}$ by a constant $C_{p,\delta} \geq 0$, hence $|f(c)| \leq C_{p,\delta} |c|^p$ if $|c| \geq \eta$.
This yields:
$$\forall c \in \mathbb{R},\quad \big ||1-c|^p - 1 - |c|^p \big |\,\, =\,\, |f(c)| \,\,\leq\,\, \delta + C_{p,\delta} |c|^p$$
and we are done with this partial answer by our previous observations.
